# GDB's break skips line on break at label

Tags: gcc, gdb, mips

Below is a debugging session of a hello world MIPS assembly program.
The program is assembled using GCC and debugged using gdb-multiarch.
Code is executed on QEMU, GDB connects to QEMUs debugging port on 8080.

When executing `break main` I expect GDB to break in line 7 (`jal hello`) but it creates the break point at line 9.

```
(gdb) file proj.out 
Reading symbols from proj.out...done.
(gdb) target remote 127.0.0.1:8080
Remote debugging using 127.0.0.1:8080
0x00400290 in _ftext ()
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400460: file /import/src/main.s, line 9.
(gdb) list
1       
2       .text
3       .globl main
4       .extern hello
5       
6       main:
7         jal hello
8       
9         li  $a0, 0
10        li  $v0, 4001
```

I could reproduce this for arbitrary labels that I added to the program. It doesn't occur when just breaking at a line without a label. But it also occurs when using `break main.s:6` instead of `break main`.

I suspect GDB to stick to some kind of convention that I are unaware of.

Program versions:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
mips-linux-gnu-gcc (Debian 4.3.5-4) 4.3.5
qemu-mips version 2.0.0 (Debian 2.0.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1.24)
operating system: ubuntu:14.04.4 docker container
```

Compilation command:

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc -g -static -mips32r5 -O0 -o
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mips architecture has "branch delay slots".

Consider a simplified view. mips has *two* separate units: an instruction *fetch* unit and an instruction *execution* unit.

The fetch unit runs "one ahead" of the execution unit. This allows the overlapping of the units. That is, the exec unit is able to operate in parallel with the fetch. It execs the inst that was fetched on the previous cycle.

So, in cycle 0, the first instruction is fetched. In cycle 1, the first instruction is executed, and the 2nd instruction is fetched. In cycle 2, the 2nd inst is executed, and the 3rd instruction is fetched. This looks like:

```
cycle       fetch       exec
0           1           n/a
1           2           1
2           3           2
3           4           3
```

This works fine until we hit a branch instruction of any kind (i.e. `jal`). In your example, we have `7 jal hello` and `9 li $a0,0`. You didn't show your C code, but I suspect that `hello` takes one argument and your actual call was `hello(0)`

So, the sequence would be `li $a0,0` and the `jal hello` on most arches.

Because the instruction fetch runs "one ahead", the prefetched instruction *after* the `jal` would have to be discarded and would be wasted.

So, mips has branch delay slots. The instruction *after* a branch is *in* the delay slot. It is *always* executed, just as if it had appeared before the branch.

So, logically, your program looks like:

```
L1:     li      $a0,0               # first arg to hello
L2:     jal     hello               # call to hello
L3:     nop                         # branch delay slot
```

The actual execution order is L1, L3, L2

The compiler was able to optimize this and put a useful instruction in the branch delay slot:

```
L1:     jal     hello               # call to hello
L2:     li      $a0,0               # first arg to hello
```

The execution order is L2, L1. Remember, for a branch [taken or *not*], the instruction in the branch delay slot is *always* executed first, just as if it came first.

So, gdb *did* put the breakpoint in the correct place: on the first instruction of main. But, because the first instruction was a branch, the correct place to put the `break` instruction is the branch delay slot for the branch.

In your example, the `jal` was line 7 and the branch delay slot for it was line 9.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Unfortunately the breakpoint is set at the wrong position regardless of the instruction: I could replace `jal hello` by `li $a0, 1` and it wouldn't change anything.

Sorry about that. The `li` should have been a clue as it's a pseudo-op and it can generate 1-2 real instructions. For example, `li $a0,0x01020304` would generate: `lui $a0,0x0102 ori $a0,$a0,0x0304`

But, you'll probably still have to be mindful of the branch delay slots. I don't know about `qemu`, but some mips simulators like `mars` or `spim` allow you to configure whether the slots are enabled/used or not [and, for them, the slot are default *off*]. If off, the slots can be ignored. Otherwise, just add a `nop` after every branch.

> The code is written "by hand" and is not compiled from C or any other language.

Again, sorry. I saw "compiled with GCC" instead of "assembled with GCC".

---

Part of the issue is that `gdb` is a high level language source debugger. That's its primary orientation. Its notion of line numbers is oriented to HLL (e.g. C) line numbers. So, it may have some difficulty mapping to/from asm line numbers without some help. Even though the source is `.s`, that could have come from `cc -c -s -o foo.s foo.c ; cc -o foo foo.s`.

`gdb` prefers that the program has been compiled with `-g`. This adds certain asm directives to define debugging information. To see what that's like, take a C program [or just about any `.c` file] and [cross] compile it using `-g` [or `-gdwarf-2`] and `-s`. Then, look at the output `.s` file.

You may need to add similar directives in places to tell `gdb` exactly what *you* think the line numbers should be. This, of course, can be done manually. But, I have been known to take a given `.s` and feed it through a "metaprogramming" script to add whatever I need. So, the output of this is what is fed to `gcc`--YMMV

---

But, whenever I've used `gdb` to debug asm, and need precision control, I use a few different gdb commands that are better oriented to debugging assembler.

`stepi` instead of `step`. This steps by single asm instructions instead of what gdb *thinks* are source lines.

`disassemble main` instead of `list main`. This gives the actual instructions instead of a source listing. Or `x/i <address>`. A good example is `x/i $pc`.

`<address>` can be a label or a simple expression using a label.

*Now, a biggie:* instead of `break <function>` or `break <line_number>`, I'll use the *address* form: `break *<address>`.

So, if `disassemble main` showed that the first instruction was at address `0x00001000`, then I'd do `break *0x1000`.

But, that would be tedious. The address form allows symbols. So, you can do `break *main`. It also allows address expressions: `break *main+0x4`. I think *"These **are** the droids you're looking for"* :-)

---

Another approach is to consider using `mars` or `spim` for simulation. They are GUI based and can be much easier to use (and come with built in assemblers).

If you're just trying to learn mips asm and doing simple stuff, they might be a better choice to start out with. Most of the questions I've seen on SO use them or do debug on real hardware [usually booted under linux].

I've not seen too many that use `qemu`. So, if you don't have an OS requirement, `mars/spim` might be worth a try. I've used both and I prefer `mars`

Depending upon how big your project is [or will become], they might still be the answer for a portion of it (i.e. isolate and debug a particular function with them).

If you'd like to give it a try, here's a link for mars: http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer.

Unfortunately the breakpoint is set at the wrong position regardless of the instruction: I could replace `jal hello` by `li $a0, 1` and it wouldn't change anything.
The code is written "by hand" and is not compiled from C or any other language.

Comment: Your hint to `break *main` was the key. `dissassemble main` is quite helpful. Thanks a lot.